# How to fix 'error 400 bad request' when making a post in react with axios?

Tags: reactjs, request, axios

I want to make a post request to add in database but I get 400 bad request error.

My express server is running on http://localhost:5000 and my react server on http://localhost:3000. The problem is that the post is on 3000 on the web instead of 5000.
The proxy is set on 5000. I have a get method also and that is running fine.

class Parts extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addPartName = this.addPartName.bind(this);
    this.addPartNumber = this.addPartNumber.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        parts: [],
        partName: '',
        partNumber: ''
    };
}


addPartName(e) {
    this.setState({
        partName: e.target.value
    })
}

addPartNumber(e) {
    this.setState({
        partNumber: e.target.value
    })
}


onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const part = {
        partName: this.state.partName,
        partNumber: this.state.partNumber
    };
    axios.post('/api/parts', part)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    this.setState({
        partName: '',
        partNumber: ''
    })
}


componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/parts')
        .then(res => {
            const parts = res.data
            this.setState({parts})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

}
```

Comment: I can see you're using both GET and POST on the same endpoint. Do you have both a GET and a POST endpoint in your express server for that endpoint? And if so, for the POST endpoint what kind of data is it expecting?

Comment: Yes, I have both a GET and a POST on that endpoint and It expects JSON